# Large amount of disk used by "System". Time machine not to blame. What's taking up so much space?

Tags: mac, hard-drive, mojave, disk-space

So, I found a number of threads related to System files on Macs taking up to much space, and it seems for most people they are related to Time Machine snap shots. However, when I run `sudo tmutil listlocalsnapshots /` it returns nothing.

Here's what it show in the Storage tab of About my Mac:

[image]

The gray bar is labelled "System" and it's taking up nearly 200 Gb of space.

I downloaded OmniDiskSweeper to get an idea of what's going on, and this is where it gets weirder.

[image]

In the drive list, it says 223 Gb are being used, but after sizing everything it says only 95 Gb are being used, and System files are just under 7 Gb.

What gives? Is there another place Time Machine snapshots could be hiding. Is there something else that would be taking up space, but is being missed by OmniDiskSweeper somehow?

Mac details:

[image]

UPDATE: Daisy Disk has revealed a file /private/var/log/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.log that is 121.6 Gb (!!?)

Is this safe to delete? I assume so, given that it's a log.

UPDATE 2: Also, how can I even delete this if it's okay to do so? I can't even get into the directory (`sudo` does nothing, and `sudo chown` doesn't allow me to `cd` into either...)

Comment: Thank you for mentioning DaisyDisk! Even just using the trial helped me find I had ~80GB of caches.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think TimeMachine backups are stored elsewhere but on my machine, the Library folder takes up 100 GB! It may be included in the system size but OmniDiskSweeper separates it out. I've asked about the library folder being so large but didn't get an adequate response. I don't know how to safely reduce the size of that folder.

You should check the results of OmniDiskSweeper to see if your Library folder is taking up a lot of space. You have 2 library folders. Check the one in the Users/yourname directory.

Comment: OmniDiskSweeper says my `~/Library` directory is taking up only 10.9 Gb (Finder Info say 11.09)

Comment: ok, sorry.  I was basing my answer on my experience.

Comment: you might check the other Library folder just for completeness...

Comment: Yeah, no worries, it was a good suggestion, just unfortunately doesn't seem to be it. `/Library` is showing between 8-9 Gb. :/

Comment: thanks. i'll keep shuffling thru my memory. if I think of something I'll leave a comment.

Comment: You could try the program Disk Inventory X. It gives a little more comprehensive look at the entire system.